# Transforming large list of label data to float for model to train

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train the basic model with the data I have below, but unfortunately, I'm stuck on a problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

Dataframe that looks like this:

```
index Author    Line1   Line2   Line3
0     Author1   13.8    6.16    0.75
1     Author1   14.13   6.09    0.8
2     Author1   20.5    15.91   0.8
3     Author2   12.45   6.35    0.83
4     Author2   15.91   6.09    0.81
...
100105 Author125 15.91   6.16    0.8
```

I have separated dataframe data and labels to train and test using code below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Data_train, Data_test, Labels_train, Labels_test = train_test_split(df[["Line1", "Line2", "Line3"]], df["Author"], test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle="true")
```

When I try to use this data in my model:

```
model = keras.Sequential( 
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(
            3, activation="relu", input_shape=(Data_train.shape[-1],)
        ),
        keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(Data_train, Labels_train, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(Data_test, Labels_test))
```

I receive error:
Node: 'Cast_1'
Cast string to float is not supported

I believe I have to pass Labels as float somehow, I found a way to make labels binary with "MultiLabelBinarizer", but because I have over 100 of them, I don't think that it would work, and I'm not sure if I should do that before separating data using train_test_split or after, if so maybe someone could help me?

Also if anyone has suggestions on the model I have, please, feel free to help me improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code I changed the Labels to numbers and was able to feed it to the network:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df["Author"] = le.fit_transform(df["Author"])
df["Author"]
```